# IPCAUClient: bundle display name is nil

Tags: ios, ios9, core-audio, avaudiosession

When I run the following command in my iOS9 application:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

Then the following message is shown on the command line:

```
ERROR: 126: IPCAUClient: bundle display name is nil
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Just found out,that `CFBundleDisplayName` entry in my Apps `info.plist` file was missing.Adding this fixed the error.

Comment: You should mark your answer as correct.  And maybe delete your duplicate Question,  or at least duplicate the answer.